# How to get JSON object on client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently attempting to send a JSON object from the server to the client but I'm not sure if I'm accessing it correctly.

```
app.post('/url', function(request, response){
....
var result = fuse.search(); 

response.json(result); // results should be sent back as a response
```

} )

```
$.post("/url", options, function(response, request) {
    var json = response.json;    
)
```

Comment: Sorry going to need more information - are you attempting to POST to the client from the server? You should be exposing an endpoint that the client can GET from. Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Well, there's an easy way to tell if you're accessing it correctly; Are you getting the data you expect? Are any errors thrown in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post

`jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

> success
>
> Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required if dataType is provided, but can be null in that case.

If you read further

> The success callback function is passed the returned data

Which probably means what you should be doing is

```
var json = response;
```

This of course assuming your request actually *did* receive the JSON